# \copy CSV with double quotes inside field to table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, postgresql, psql

This is how the CSV file looks like:

```
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6
"153";"0";"5";"39264";"hey";"4 spaces; not"can;hen" thanks!"
```

The last field contains double quotes and semicolons inside the string. When I try to copy the file to the table like so:

```
psql -U user -d postgres -c "\copy file from 'file.csv' with delimiter as ';' csv header;"
```

I get the error `ERROR:  extra data after last expected column.`

The double quotes and semicolons only exist in the last column.

How can I alter the `psql` command so that this CSV table is successfully copied?

Comment: a pandas solution would also be great. However, I cannot use regex operators on parameter `sep` because I have `low_memory=False` on. I can only use the c engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot alter the command, you have to alter the file, because the file is not syntactically correct CSV.

You'd have to double the double quotes that are *not* field delimiters:

```
"153";"0";"5";"39264";"hey";"4 spaces; not""can;hen"" thanks!"
```